# View close votes

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Is there a way to view a list of all the close votes that I have cast (similar to viewing the flags that I have sent)?

Its not really that important, but I was just curious if there was a way.

Comment: As I cannot suggest and edit by doing it, I suggest to edit the title to be "View own close votes".

Answer (score 5):

Votes you have cast to close or migrate, no.

Votes to close on your own question, [when you hit 250](https://superuser.com/privileges/view-close-votes).

Votes to close on the question you're looking at, [when you hit 3000.](https://superuser.com/privileges/close-questions)

Votes to close across other questions at a glance, [when you hit 10,000.](https://superuser.com/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: Why not to close or migrate?